# Android emulator crashing ubuntu when interacting with panel

Tags: android

I am using ubuntu 20.04. I recently installed android studio, and the emulator seems to be buggy at best. Specifically when I interact with the side panel of the AVD instance, it crashes. Inspecting `journalctl` it yields the following error

```
Sep 30 18:57:45 jonas-computer kernel: Code: c8 48 c1 e9 38 48 83 f9 01 77 09 4d 8d 41 ff 4d 21 d8 eb 13 4d 89 d8 4d 39 cb 72 0b 4c 89 d8 31 d2 49 f7 f1 49 89 d0 48 8b 07 <4a> 8b 04 c0 48 85 c0 0f 84 8e 00 00 00 48 8b 30 48 85 f6 0f 84 82
Sep 30 18:57:45 jonas-computer kernel: MainLoopThread[86971]: segfault at 90 ip 00007f9700a5fc84 sp 00007f9661eec428 error 4 in libOpenglRender.so[7f9700a2e000+317000]
Sep 30 18:57:45 jonas-computer kernel: Code: c8 48 c1 e9 38 48 83 f9 01 77 09 4d 8d 41 ff 4d 21 d8 eb 13 4d 89 d8 4d 39 cb 72 0b 4c 89 d8 31 d2 49 f7 f1 49 89 d0 48 8b 07 <4a> 8b 04 c0 48 85 c0 0f 84 8e 00 00 00 48 8b 30 48 85 f6 0f 84 82
```

and crashes the application. Android studio yields following error:

```
2021-09-30 18:57:45,396 [22493427]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554 
2021-09-30 18:57:45,432 [22493463]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code 139
```

Most suggestions with the error seems to revolve around old/updated drivers for graphics, however my machine does not have any graphics card and I have chosen to use software to emulate graphics.

I am not sure what to make of the error.

Comment: That may be a totally different thing, (though the kernel message points in the same direction) but I'm only able to run the android emulator with the `-gpu swiftshader_indirect` command line option, otherwise it crashes. Sooner or later. I'm using the android sdk from the command line, I have no idea how to add that option when it's started from Android Studio.

Comment: Cross-posted on Ubuntu.SE: https://askubuntu.com/q/1366716/331791